# how to create instant messaging app in android

Tags: java, android-studio, instant-messaging

I want to implement an instant messaging feature in my android app which will show the chat list of the current user and the conversation with each of them. I want to know which is the best option for doing so because i have heard about various feature like pusher,gcm,xmpp,etc.

I am using retrofit 2.0,php and mysql now in my app to create messaging feature,everything is working out great but but i cant figure out how to show the message received or send in the conversation instantly because for that network request call has to called every time the received or send and i have a feeling i might not be good idea as it will slow down app or something.

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: you start with an analysis and requirements. then you start implementing and testing.  But this is way to broad for SO

Comment: can u be specific? i already done my analysis and requirements and all, i am just stuck in what i have written in second paragraph

Comment: no, that is what you should do. this question is not really SO related, you should chck with one of the other domains

Comment: other domain like?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would look at https://socket.io/. There is also a demo [project for Android chat app](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat)